# Embrac package and enumerate

Tags: formatting, italic, embrac

In using the [embrac package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embrac) to make parentheses appear upright in `\emph` evironments, I noticed that it did work in most cases, but not in an enumerate environment that appeared in a theorem (where text appears fully slanted).

This is my setup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, enumitem}
\usepackage{embrac}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
This holds:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

In the (i) in the enumeration, the brackets still appear slanted.

[image]

Comment: Please, could you add a picture into your question? Thank you very much.

Comment: `embrac` does not redefine `\em` it only changes `\emph`, so it does not apply in your `lemma` at all. Try `This holds: (i)` for example to see that the brackets are unaffected. I believe it would be non-trivial to get `\em` to be `embrac`-ified, hence I suggest you go with `[label=\upshape(\roman*)]`, you could possibly wrap that up in a `\setlist` in the preamble to only type this once.

Comment: @Sebastiano My apologies; added.

Comment: @moewe Thank you, I did not know that `\em` was used in a `lemma` environment. That workaround should solve it.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht No apologies :-). My English language is very bad. With the pcture I can understand the question.

Comment: In any event, it's better style to use upright labels in lists that appear in theorems.  So the `\upshape` suggestion by @moewe is really the best approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Section 9 *Watch Out!* of the [`embrac` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/embrac/embrac_en.pdf) explains that `embrac` only applies to `\emph{...}`, but not to `{\em ...}` and `{\itshape ...}`. Since `amsthm`'s `lemma` uses `\itshape` to typeset its body in italics, `embrac` can't be used here. It would be a non-trivial (impossible?) exercise to convert `embrac`'s behaviour for the macro `\emph` to the switch `\itshape`, so you will have to find a different work-around. The easiest is to use `\upshape` for the label. Since you use `enumitem` you can pack that up into a global definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, enumitem}
\usepackage{embrac}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\setlist[enumerate]{label=\upshape(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
This holds:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image: enumerate item in upright font]

or define a new list type `thmenum`

```
\newlist{thmenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmenum]{label=\upshape(\roman*)}
```

and then use it like this

```
\begin{lemma}
This holds:
\begin{thmenum}
  \item $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{thmenum}
\end{lemma}
```

if you want to preserve the original `enumerate`. The result is the same.

> As clemens mentions in the comment, v0.8 of `embrac` introduces the macro `\embparen` which can be used as follows
>
> ```
> \setlist[enumerate]{label=\embparen{\roman*}}
> ```

Comment: Perhaps `label={{\upshape(}\roman*{\upshape)}}` might be better so that only the paren are upright.

Comment: with v0.8 (available in the next days) `embrac` provides `\embparen` which would allow to say `\setlist[enumerate]{label=\embparen{\roman*}}`

Comment: @clemens Thanks for the heads-up. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

this also works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, embrac}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lemma}
This holds:
\begin{enumerate}[label=$(\roman*)$]
    \item $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{enumerate}
    \end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

[image]