# Upright brackets in theorem body with bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape?

Tags: theorems, thmtools, embrac

Is it possible to make square brackets in the body of a theorem appear upright — when using the declaration `bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape` in the definition of a theoremstyle with `thmtools`?

The method of using the package `embrac`([Copy theoremfont option from newtxtext](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423432/copy-theoremfont-option-from-newtxtext)) does not work, because as the `embrac` documentation says, it affects only `\emph`, `\textit`, and `textsl` but not `\itshape` or `\slshape`.

In particular: **is there a way to avoid using `\itshape` (or `\slshape`) yet still obtain italic (or slant, respectively) in the body of a theorem** when the theoremstyle is defined using `thmtools`? (except for the desired upright brackets, of course).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{embrac}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}% default
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}

\begin{theorem}

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets [see section 2] of a set $X$.Then
\[
X \setminus (A \cup B) = (X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus B).
\]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Want upright brackets in theorem body text]

I am aware of the answer to [How to get upright parentheses in the whole document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86112/how-to-get-upright-parentheses-in-the-whole-document), which, as it says, will break things.

Comment: It's probably necessary to attack them one by one.  You can do this as `\textup[` or `\textup]`.  Braces around the square brackets aren't necessary, since `\textup` operates on only the next token, and a single character here is the token.  (A long time ago, there was a discussion about creating a "theorem font", italic with upright punctuation.  But it never happened, as the complications weren't easy to work around.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I'm already aware of just using `\textup`, but I was hoping for something more high-level -- a way to do what the `theoremfont` option of `newtxtext` does automatically.

Comment: The crux of my question is the bolded sentence: is there a way to avoid using `\itshape` or `slshape` as value for option `bodyfont` in `\declaretheoremstyle` from `thmtools` (i.e., somehow use `\textit` or `\textsl` there), so that `embrac` would work.

Comment: The `scholax` package includes a style option `theoremfont` that does make text parentheses, brackets, and braces upright. The method seems to be simply: `\DeclareRobustCommand\thfamily
        {\not@math@alphabet\thfamily\relax
         \fontfamily\thdefault\selectfont}
\AtEndPreamble{\patchcmd{\th@plain}{\itshape}{\thfamily}{}{}}
%
\newcommand*{\thdefault}{\rmdefault}`

Comment: However, the method quoted from `scholax` does not seem to work if I use `thmtools` and declare the theorem style body font to be `\slshape`.

Comment: The rationale for using `\itshape` instead of `\textit` or `\emph` in `amsthm` is that `\itshape` continues through paragraph breaks and math displays, while the commands taking arguments do not.  It might be possible to define something like `\aside{1}{\textup[#1\/\textup]}` to handle such insertions.  Not tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 0.8 (2019/10/01) `embrac` provides `\embparen` and `\embbracket` for cases like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{embrac}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}% default
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}

\begin{theorem}
  Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets \embbracket{see section 2} of a set $X$.Then
  \[ X \setminus (A \cup B) = (X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus B). \]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the documentation, it should not be necessary to use `\embracket` explicilty: from its page 2, "embrac tries to redefine \emph, \textit and \textsl in a way that neither parentheses nor square brackets are sloped.". Moreover, having to type `\embbracket{see section 2}` defeats the purpose of `embrac`, namely, to avoid having to manually indicate that such brackets in emphasized, italicized, or slanted text are to be typeset upright.

Comment: @murray The theorem uses neither of `\emph`, `\textit` or `\textsl`. It uses `\itshape`. Please read the section in the `embrac` manual called “Watch out!“ again.

Comment: `\embbracket` inserts the correct kerns so it is an compromise between having an automated solution and having to use `\textup{[}`.

Comment: Related discussion https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461592/

Comment: The compromise noted! Of course part of the difficulty is that `thmtools` demands use of the argument-free `\itshape`, `\slshape`, etc. commands instead of somehow employing the argument-using `textit` and `\textsl`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to forgo verbatim material in your theorems, you can process the body of the theorem with `embrac`'s `\embrac_replace_brackets:N` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embrac}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \murray_embrac_text:n #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__embrac_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \embrac_replace_brackets:N \l__embrac_tmpa_tl
    \l__embrac_tmpa_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \embracifytheorem } { m }
  {
    \NewEnvironmentCopy { origenv_#1 } { #1 }
    \RenewDocumentEnvironment { #1 } { o +b }
      {
        \IfNoValueTF{##1}
          {\begin{origenv_#1}}
          {\begin{origenv_#1}[##1]}
        \murray_embrac_text:n { ##2 }
        \end{origenv_#1}
      }
      {}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% you can adjust or remove these to your liking
\AddOpEmph{?}[0pt,1pt]
\AddOpEmph{!}[0pt,1pt]
\AddOpEmph{:}[0pt,1pt]

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}% default
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\embracifytheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{theorem}

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets [see section 2] of a set $X$.Then
\[
X \setminus (A \cup B) = (X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus B).
\]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: thm]