# How make newtx option theoremfont work with thmtools?

Tags: theorems, brackets, thmtools, newtx

I want the body of theorems to be in a true slanted font (`\slshape`) rather than in italic, yet have brackets within a theorem body to be upright.

The newtx package (version 1.7) option theoremfont (and the same option to the newtxtext package) makes text in the body of an amsthm theorem body slanted yet keep brackets there upright.

Is it possible somehow to cause that same option to have the same effect when declaring theorem styles via the thmtools package?

If, as in the following source, I use newtx option `theoremfont` and define the theorem style via thmtools, then the entire theorem body font is upright, including brackets there.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[amsthm,theoremfont]{newtx} % loads fontspec & amsthm, too

\usepackage{thmtools}
\swapnumbers
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries, headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  % bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The Chapter}
\section{Here is a section}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean theorem]

In a right triangle [that is, with one angle a right angle],
the square of the length of the hypotenuse equals
the sum of the squares of the lengths of the other two sides.

\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: newtx with theoremfont option and thmtools - no bodyfont declared]

If, however, I add to the theorem style definition the option

```
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
```

then the entire theorem body is slanted, including, unfortunatetly, brackets, as shown here:

[image: newtx with theoremfont option and thmtools with slshape bodyfont declared]

I am aware of two workarounds:

1. load package embrac and then use `\embbracket{...}` for the bracketed text; or
2. use `\textup{[}` and `\textup{]}1 to delimit the bracketed text.

But both methods are "manual," whereas I am looking for an automatic method.

Related:

[Upright brackets in theorem body with bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519000/upright-brackets-in-theorem-body-with-bodyfont-mdseries-itshape)

[Embrac package and enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461581/embrac-package-and-enumerate/461592#461592)

[Upright parentheses in italic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13048/upright-parentheses-in-italic-text)

[Copy theoremfont option from newtxtext](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423432/copy-theoremfont-option-from-newtxtext)

**Added: comparison with newtx and amsthm**

By contrast, the following source produces a theorem body with slanted text, except that brackets, parentheses, numerals, and punctuation are set upright:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[amsthm,theoremfont]{newtx}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}

In a right triangle [that is, a triangle with one right angle]: the square of (the length of) the hypotenuse equals the some of the squares of the other 2 sides.

\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image: upright brackets, etc. - newtx, theoremfont opt, amsthm]

Comment: You might reach out to the package author (Michael Sharpe) directly.

Comment: I'm not sure you're reading the documentation correctly. Up to version 1.65, `\slshape` and `\textsl` were abused to produce the “theorem font”, but now there's `\thfamily` to that effect. Nowhere it is said that a slanted font with upright punctuation and figures is available.

Comment: @egreg: I only want to be able to use a slanted font with upright brackets in the body of theorems created using thmtools. I do not need any more general such slanted font.

Comment: @murray I know of no font that provides that.

Comment: @egreg: Since the newtx packages do what I want (when option `theoremfont` is included) with amsthm theorems, I was hoping there was some way it could be done with thmtools theorems.

Comment: @murray You don't get upright punctuation and numerals, do you?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, with amsthm (instead of thmtools) and the `theoremfont` option to newtx, I do get upright brackets, parentheses, numerals in the otherwise slanted theorem body text. See the "Added: comparison..." in my question.

Comment: @murray I see slanted punctuation in the first image with slanted type, and upright punctuation with *italic* type in the second image. Nowhere I see upright punctuation *and* slanted type.

Comment: @murray To be more precise, in the last image, what you call “slanted” is clearly italic.

Comment: The newtx package author Michael Sharpe posted a new version, dated January 9, 2022, that includes a new option `thmslshape` allowing option `bodyfont=\thfamily` for the thmtools command `\declaretheoremstyle`. This makes the body text of theorems to be slanted (not italic) while keeping punctuation and numerals upright.

Comment: @murray Perhaps you can write this as an answer to your question?

Comment: @mbert: Something's wrong now when I try using `thmslshape` option for `newtx` with `bodyfont=\thfamily` for `\declaretheoremstyle`: parentheses and brackets disappear from the body of theorems! I'm afraid I'm not understanding the interaction amont `newtx` options `theoremfont`, `trueslanted` and `thmslshape`.

Comment: Hmm yes adding `thmslshape` produces a bunch of "glyph undefined" warnings.

Answer (score 1):

At least with `newtx` version 1.732, we get slanted text for the body of theorems (but upright parentheses and brackets there) by using option `thmslshape` (*without* option `theoremfont`) together with keyword value `bodyfont=\thfamily` in a `thmtools` theorem-style declaraion.

This works with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex`.

For example:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[amsthm,thmslshape]{newtx} % loads fontspec & amsthm, too
  
  \usepackage{thmtools}
  \swapnumbers
  \declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\sffamily\bfseries, headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
    bodyfont=\thfamily,
  ]{thmstyle}
  \declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem]{theorem}
  
  \begin{document}
  
  \section{Here is a section}
  
  \begin{theorem}[Pythagorean theorem]
  
  In a right triangle [that is, with one angle a right angle],
  the square of the length of the hypotenuse (the slanted side if the legs are parallel to the axes!) equals
  the sum of the squares of the lengths of the other two sides.
  
  \end{theorem}
  
  In normal text that is \emph{emphasized (that is, by default italicized),} we do not get slanted.
  
  \end{document}
```

[image: slanted theorem body font with newtx]

Comment: With v1.734 the options `thmslshape,theoremfont` seem to work together fine

Comment: @mbert: I believe you're correct that `theoremfont` here, when using `thmtools`, will do no harm. But it won't do any good, either, because, according to the docs, it merely affects the `plain` theormstyle when using `amsthm` without `thmtools`.